# Martin Luther King Speech

Tags: copyright, archive

I'm designing a human rights documentary and there are shots being used of Mr. Martin Luther King in Washington D.C.

Could someone please point me in the direction of where I can find the original audio clips to use? "I have a dream today"?

Is it legal to use this audio? The picture editors using the picture do not have the audio and I figure if they have the OK to use the pictures, I would have the OK to use the audio, right?

Also please let me know if I'm not supposed to use the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.archive.org/details/MLKDream

There ya go - public archive.

Comment: All formats, and Public Domain for free use.

Comment: I think everyone should download this and have it in their library in case they need it.